# Can I use metal wire ties to secure BX to the steel stud?

Tags: wiring

In steel stud construction, are you allowed to use metal wire (like re-bar tie wire) to strap BX armoured cable to the steel studs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I secure cable to a metal stud](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68723/how-can-i-secure-nm-cable-to-a-metal-stud).

Comment: Bx or AC/MC are not Romex and require different methods. Also code requirements change so if no code reference is provided what may have been good 6 or 7 years ago is a code violation today. As zip ties now require listing for the type of anchor used.

Answer (score 0):

Both ac & mc cable types require listed ties and have for a couple of code cycles NEC 320.30 & 330.30.

My jurisdiction did not adopt the “listed” requirement so I can use wire ties in some cases but in the case of a stud they usually want the one hole straps some studs have punch outs that you can fold over 1/2 & 3/4 but if you have to mod the stud they want a strap for me.

This is without the listing required as in the code according to table 1E of Oregon amendments.